# How to handle Multiple Authorization Servers to prevent Token Issued Failure

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Set-up: I have two servers which both have an individual IIS instance of my .NET Core OpenId Authorization application.

There is an intermittent issue occurring whereby if the user's request started on Server 1, at some point during the requests the user's request is moved over to Server 2, then authorisation fails with the following message:

```
    Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token

    ...

    fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]

    Invalid authorization code{ code = REDACTED }, details: {

    ...

    "GrantType": "authorization_code",
    "Error": "invalid_grant",
    "Category": "Token",
    "Name": "Token Issued Failure",
    "EventType": "Failure",
```

It seems that if my load balancer has moved the user over to the opposite server, then the request to /connect/token is always failing with the above. However, if I am to take one of my servers offline and retest the authorization request, then it is working perfectly well.

How do I go about allowing both of my servers to accept requests to /connect/token even if the request started on the opposite server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that you need to keep track of when you use load-balancers.

First of all you need to make sure the session cookie works across both machines and you need to provide a shared data protection key that both services uses.

Do you have one more multiple IdentityServer instances? regardless you should also provide a proper token signing key and not using the **AddDeveloperSigningCredential** method in your startup class.

When a user is asked to signin, the instance (with AddOpenIDConnect) should be the same instance that also handles the callback from IdentityServer (the request to /signin-oidc).

For example the **state** parameter and **PKCE** values are not shared across the instances.

I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I'm currently using RsaKeyService as opposed to AddDeveloperSigningCredential, where the two individual instances have unique rsakey.json files. Just to test I did make both of these rsakey.json files the same but the same issue persisted. I do have multiple IdentityServer instances, one for each server, but both are exactly the same application files except for the rsakey.json files. In this case do you think I still need to configure a shared data protection key? I'll try to do some research for this too, thanks!

Comment: The Token Signing Key and the Data Protection Key should be the same across all instances if you want the users to seamless move between the machines. I did blog about the data protection api here https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault

Comment: But as I also said, the instance of the (AddOpenIDConnect...) handler should also be the same that handles the entire "signing flow". otherwise you will have state/PKCE... issues.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to have resolved my issue - I have put in place the following: 

            string sKeysPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Keys");
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("My Application")
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(sKeysPath));

Placed the automatically generated Key from one server onto the opposite server, but the issue is persistent. Just to clarify, the AddOpenIDConnect is coming from the client's application.

Comment: Just a short update - I have been able to get this working now. I hadn't yet implemented my own PersistedGrantStore, so the supplied authorization_code from the /authorization endpoint couldn't be found when the opposite server was requesting the /token endpoint. A combination of this and also using the DataProtection that you advised have allowed this to be resolved. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out!